# Using the maximum principle on a rectangle to find properties on an infinite strip

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $S$ be the strip $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Re}(z)\in(0,1)\}$ and let $f:\overline{S}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a bounded and continuous function that is holomorphic on $S$.

We have been given a proof structure to ultimately arrive at:
$$\sup_{z\in\partial S}\left|f(z)\right|=\sup_{z\in S}\left|f(z)\right|$$

The first step has me very confused:

> Let $\epsilon, \delta > 0$. Pick $z_0 \in S$ such that $|f(z_0)|>(1-\epsilon)\sup_{z\in S}|f(z)|$. Take the function $f_\delta(z)=e^{\delta(z-z_0)^2}f(z)$. Show that $$\sup_{z\in\partial S}\left|f_\delta(z)\right|\ge(1-\epsilon)\sup_{z\in S}\left|f(z)\right|$$
>   You may want to use the classical maximum principle on a suitable rectangle $(0,1)\times(-A,A)$

The hint has me confused on multiple levels. First off: I don't see the relationship between $f_\delta$ and $(1-\epsilon)f$, how could we even apply the maximum principle?

Also, how can a result on a rectangle give us the desired result on the entire infinite strip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $f_{\delta}(z_0)=f(z_0),$ so, by our choice of $z_0$, all we have to do is to guarantee that $\sup_{z\in \partial S}|f_{\delta}(z)|\geq |f_{\delta}(z_0)|.$

Let $S_A=(0,1)\times (-A,A),$ we of course know that $\sup_{s\in \partial S_A} |f_{\delta}(z)|\geq |f_{\delta}(z_0)|,$ when $A$ is suitably large by the usual maximum principle. Now, for $z\in [0,1]\times \{\pm A\},$ we have

$$
|\exp(\delta(z-z_0)^2)|= \exp(\delta ((\Re(z-z_0))^2 -(\Im(z-z_0))^2)\leq \exp(\delta(1-(A-|z_0|)^2)),
$$

which goes to $0$ uniformly in $z$ as $A\to \infty$. Since $f$ is assumed bounded, the same conclusion goes for $f_{\delta}$. Hence, pick $A$ so large that $|f_{\delta}(z)|\leq |f(z_0)|/2$ for all $z\in [0,1]\times \{\pm A\}$. Then, from our observation before, we see that

$$
|f_{\delta}(z_0)|\leq \sup_{z\partial S_A} |f_{\delta}(z)|=\sup_{z\in (\{0\}\cup \{1\})\times [-A,A]} |f_{\delta}(z)|\leq \sup_{z\in \partial S}|f_{\delta}(z)|,
$$

establishing the desired.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that we need *way less* for this part of the argument than $f$ being bounded. All we need is that $f$ grows sub-exponentially.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow your argument for the $\exp()$ part. I have checked with a graphic calculator, it's right, but for instance, why can you just swap the $\Re$/$\Im$ operators and the squares?

Comment: I'm using that $|\exp(z)|=\exp(\Re z)$ and $\Re z^2=(\Re z)^2-(\Im z)^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that one!